# How to debug or trace requests to Shops Role

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is there a way to view/trace/debug requests made to the commerce Shops Role in real time and see which ones are cached and which are not etc?

If you look at this video https://youtu.be/bnFBM7veTtY?list=PL1jJVFm_lGny-vqNPTv3VdBA_o31-Tq94&t=625 (~10:25) you see what I am talking about. User requests a page, SXA storefront site in CD environment calls Sitecore Web DB and Web Index and calls Shops Role to request product data from shared environments.

I'm wondering if (locally) I can view the traffic in fiddler, somehow?
I'm using Sitecore 9 update 2 and Commerce 9 update 3.

Comment: See this blog post https://vipinbankablog.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/capture-sitecore-commerce-engine-api-calls-from-your-sitecore-storefront-in-fiddler/

Comment: @VipinBanka Perfect! If you could add those steps as an answer, I'll be happy to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fiddler to trace traffic in real time.

To setup fiddler tracing do following:

1. Add a http binding (not localhost) to your commerce engine website in IIS.
2. Add the host name in your windows host file (if it is not there).
3. Update Commerce engine service Urls in file Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config. You can find this file at location {Your-Sitecore-Website-root}\App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine. In the file change host name in "shopsServiceUrl" and "commerceOpsServiceUrl".
4. In your Sitecore website web.config file add following in <configuration> section:[image]
5. Restart Sitecore website IIS AppPool.
6. Install and start Fiddler.
7. Open storefront website in web browser.